# I am trying to webscrape to pycharm using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, pycharm

This is the HTML text that gives the output -£0.03.

I`d like to find this value by xpath and print the output to pycharm console.

```
<div class="pnl runner-info-elem below-runner-info" ng-if="ctrl.vm.events.shouldShowPnl(runner)" ng-class="{'below-runner-info': ctrl.vm.data.displayRaceCardInfo}">
<!---->
<mv-runner-pnl ng-repeat="(type, pnl) in ctrl.vm.data.pnl[runner.key] track by type" type="actual" values="pnl.values" separator="comma" formatter="::pnl.formatter">

<!-- PnL -->
<div class="runner-elem-pnl actual-pnl">
    <span class="prefix"></span>
    <span class="pnl-value-container"> 
        <span class="pnl-value negative">-£0.03</span> 
    </span>
    <span class="pnl-value-container hidden"><span>
```

I have tried the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-wrapper"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/bf-main-market/bf-main-marketview/div/div[2]/bf-marketview-runners-list[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/div[3]').get_attribute(pnl.value)

print(pnl.value)
```

My result is:

> :NameError: name 'pnl' is not defined

Is this even possible? If not by xpath then by any other means?
As I said I am totally new to this and trying to learn from YouTube tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the provided html, you could use:

```
el= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/mv-runner-pnl/div[@class='runner-elem-pnl actual-pnl']/span[@class='pnl-value-container']/span[@class='pnl-value negative']")
print(el.text)
```

Comment: Thank you ! that was exactly what i needed. I`m sorry if the question was not well formulated.

Comment: @Simon Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: sorry it took so long, i did not know how to accept your answer.but after a google search i got there in the end. can i now use the output in my script ? rather than print it to the console i`d like to use it in an if statement. for example if el >100 then do something else ?

Comment: To do that, first you have to remove the "£" character: newel = el.text.replace("£", "") and after you can do the if statement (converting the string in float): if float(newel)>100

Comment: @Simon the "newel" is a string, not a webelement. That's why you have this error. If you want to print it, you have to do print(newel)